# SwiftUI 2 accessing AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swiftui, appdelegate

I did a small prototype which uses Firebase Cloud Messaging and the new SwiftUI 2 app life cycle. I added a custom AppDelegate via
`@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate` and disabled method swizzeling for FCM to work. Everything is working as expected.

Today a colleague asked me, if one can get that delegate object via `UIApplication.shared.delegate`. So I gave it a shot and noticed that there seems to be two different AppDelegate objects:

`po delegate` prints:

```
<MyProject.AppDelegate: 0x6000009183c0>
```

where as `po UIApplication.shared.delegate` prints:

```
▿ Optional<UIApplicationDelegate>
  ▿ some : <SwiftUI.AppDelegate: 0x600000b58ca0>
```

Now I'm wondering what is the correct way of accessing the AppDelegate? Should one get it via an `@EnvironmentalObject` and pass it along all views? Or use the old fashioned way via `UIApplication`?
Additionally I would like to understand why I end up with two AppDelegates.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `MyProject.AppDelegate` is not direct `UIApplicationDelegate`, it is transferred via adapter to internal private `SwiftUI.AppDelegate`, which is real `UIApplicationDelegate` and which propagates some delegate callback to your instance.

So the solution might be:

1. Use `@EnvironmentalObject` if you need access to your `MyProject.AppDelegate` only in SwiftUI view hierarchy (for this `AppDelegate` must conform to `ObservableObject`).
2. Add and use `MyProject.AppDelegate` static property which is initialized with object created via adapter, like

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    static private(set) var instance: AppDelegate! = nil
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        AppDelegate.instance = self    // << here !!
        return true
    }
}
```

now everywhere in your code you can access your delegate via `AppDelegate.instance`.

Comment: Thanks!! Took forever to find a solution to accessing AppDelegate in UIKit classes that are inside a SwiftUI App.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor as in this [tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app)

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I created this, now I want to use that appDelegate in different struct, How I can use this?

Comment: if you have a property in MyApp that needs an instance of the appDelegate, you can pass it on the .onAppear { myController.appDelegate = appDelegate }